# How are hash maps implemented in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

How is `mymap[key]++` visualized. Am I incrementing the key or the value? 
 
 In LINE 1 `hash[numberToFind]` is the key or the value that I am inserting into the result?

```
    unordered_map<int, int> hash;
    vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        int numberToFind = target - arr[i];
        if (hash.find(numberToFind) != hash.end()) {
            result.push_back(hash[numberToFind]); //LINE 1
            result.push_back(i);        
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Wait, is this your code, or some code you found and don't understand?

Comment: It's Code I found and didn't understand. I'm trying to learn how maps are implemented in problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider going to a good reference before asking on stackoverflow.com. cppreference.com is pretty good.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

1. `key` is the key.
2. `mymap[key]` returns a reference to the element in `mymap` at key `key`.
3. If `key` is not yet in `mymap`, `mymap[key]` default constructs an element at `key` and then returns a reference to it.
4. `mymap[key]++` increments the element in `mymap` at key `key`. The rule from above still holds: if `key` is not yet in `mymap`, then an element is default constructed in `mymap` at key `key`, and then incremented.
5. `myvec.push_back(mymap[key])` creates a copy of the value at `key`, and adds it to the end of `myvec`. The copying a a function of how `push_back` works. `push_back` only adds copies of elements to the end of the vector. The rule from above still holds: if `key` is not yet in `mymap`, then an element is default constructed in `mymap` at key `key`, and then copied into `myvec`.
6. `numbers[i]` is a reference to the `i`th element in `std::vector<int> numbers`. Vectors do not default create elements at an index if there's not already an element at that index. Instead, accessing an out of bounds index is undefined behavior.
7. `hash[x]` is a reference to the element in `std::unordered_map<int, int> hash` at key `x`. Default creates, as above, if necessary.
8. `hash[numbers[i]]` is a reference to the element in `hash` at key `numbers[i]`. Default creates as above, if necessary.
9. `hash[numbers[i]] = i;` sets the element in `hash` at key `numbers[i]` to the value of `i`.